# Is my interpretation of pglmm (package phyr) output correct? Does model specification make sense?

Tags: covariance, phylogeny

I am trying to address a question related to possible effects of ‘common descent’ (i.e. phylogeny) on an observed relationship between a response and a (species-level) predictor.

I’ve been using the `phyr` package to walk my way through the `pglmm` options for testing phylogenetics as part of the random effects structure, and and I am running into some issues with parts of the code.

Specifically, following some other examples, I have taken residuals from our top model and am attempting to test for phylogenetic covariance in those residuals, using the following:

```
M1 <-pglmm(residuals ~ 1 + (1|sp),data= dat, family="gaussian",sp=tree1) ##(sp = species designation)
```

Based on the summary for this model, it appears that species accounts for approximately 6% of the variance in the residuals, but I am not entirely convinced that the phylogenetic correction is in there.

```
Linear mixed model fit by restricted maximum likelihood

Call:residuals ~ 1

logLik    AIC    BIC 
-26467  52941  52958 

Random effects:
         Variance Std.Dev
1|sp        2.012   1.418
residual   29.821   5.461

Fixed effects:
              Value Std.Error Zscore Pvalue
(Intercept) 0.35232   0.50717 0.6947 0.4873
```

According to the phyr documentation, the code should look like that below, with the double underscore after sp specifying the phylogenetic covariance:

```
M2 <- pglmm(residuals ~ 1 + (1|sp__), data = dat, family = "gaussian", cov_ranef = list(sp = tree1))
```

However, this model will not run for me. The error seems to be related to the fact that object '`Vphy`' cannot be found.

Can anybody familiar with '`phyr`' explain to me if the first model is in fact accounting for phylogenetic covariance, and if not, is there a coding change that I can make to get the output I need?

With many thanks.